# Regex for detecting a specific word preceded by any set of numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

What is the regex for detecting a specific word preceded by any combinations of numbers?

Example:

```
123 Box

1 Box

21245 Box
```

Comment: What is the regex for number? What about multiple numbers?

Comment: It's just a street address so multiple sets of numbers not required, just the first set of numbers before the street name. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The word should match, now you need to do digits `[0-9] or \d` followed by the `+` which is one or more:

```
 box [0-9]+
```

or

```
 box \d+
```

Answer (score 0):

/[0-9]+[bB]ox/ should work for this

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex like this:

```
\b(\d+ box)\b
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/oI4kO0/1)**

[image]

The idea of the regex is to capture the numbers and the box word, so using `\b` (word delimiter) it will exclude words like `boxer` and also exclude invalid numbers like `a123`. Note that I used the insensitive flag, so if you need a case sensitive match just remove the `i` flag and use `\b(\d+ Box)\b` instead.

Match information:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [27-34] `123 Box`
MATCH 2
1.  [35-40] `1 Box`
MATCH 3
1.  [41-50] `21245 Box`
```

If you don't want to capture the content and only match the pattern you have to remove the parentheses.